# how to use Google plus integration in titanium?

Tags: android, titanium, google-plus, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

I am working with an application in which i have to integrate Google plus using Titanium.

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    barColor : '#000',
    navBarHidden : true
});
var textToShare = encodeURIComponent('This text will be shared');
var urlToShare = encodeURIComponent('http://www.company.com');
var webView = Ti.UI.createWebView({
    url : 'https://plus.google.com/share?client_id=123456789.apps.googleusercontent.com&continue=' + Ti.App.id + '%3A%2F%2Fshare%2F&text=' + textToShare + '&url=' + urlToShare + '&bundle_id=' + Ti.App.id + '&gpsdk=1.0.0'
});
win.add(webView);
var close = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title : 'Close'
});
close.addEventListener('click', function() {
    win.close();
});
win.open({
    modal : true
});

webView.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
    if (e.url.indexOf('https://accounts.google.com') == -1) {
        //win.hideNavBar();
    } else {
        // win.showNavBar();
        win.setLeftNavButton(close);
    }
});
webView.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
    win.close();
});
```

It causes 404 (the requested url was not found on this server) error in webView, after google account login.I want to integrate google plus in titanium
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You have to log in to [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/) and in your project enable **Google+ API** and than inside Google+ API settings from left side menu chose **Credentials** and **Create new Client ID** for **Installed application** providing your package name (value from `Ti.App.id`).

Notice that your package name has to contain at least one `.` character:

- `testapp` – invalid
- `mycompany.testapp` – correct